# Queries on compound pk

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, compound-key

when using compound pk, can insertion of values be the same ? I illustrate an example to you guys:

Creation of table:

```
Create table test
(
testno number(5) not null,
testpaper varchar(2) not null,
time date
CONSTRAINT Pa_Pks PRIMARY KEY (testno, testpaper) 
)
```

Then this is the values that i would like insert:

```
Testno          Testpaper         Time
12345           22                14-JUL-2011
12345           23                15-JUL-2011
12345           22                16-JUL-2011
```

As you can see that my primary keys have the same values during insertion. The reason of why i would like to do that is the same testno and testpaper can happen on different dates.

How can i do that if i would like to add in same values but label it as primary key?

This should be the standard and correct way to do it:

```
Create table TEST
(
 Testid number(1) not null,
 testno number(5) not null,
 testpaper varchar(2) not null,
 time date
 CONSTRAINT Pa_Pks PRIMARY KEY (Testid) 
)
```

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant do that, Primary Key has to be Unique. However what you can do is that you can add  Test Time as part of the Key. Or you can have another column name as Id, this will be an Auto Increment Key. So your Primary Key will be ID (Auto Increment).

In oracle if you want to have an AutoIncrement Key, then you will have to write sequence and trigger also. A sequence is simply a series of number. The purpose of trigger will be to increment the number whenever new row is inserted, and store it in the column id. , And you may also wanna increase the size of Number. Number(1) might not be good enough size for primary key.(If you want Oracle to have an auto increment Id) OR Simple you can add Time to your primary Key.

The standard depends on your requirement. Both approaches are followed.

Comment: I know. Is there any way to identify it as primary key but at the same time insert same values? That's what i would like to ask,

Comment: @user976050: **NO** - your primary key **MUST** be unique by definition, so you **CANNOT** have duplicate values....

Comment: Ok understood. Even i add test time as part of my key. It would do any help right ? I'm still not able to insert any same values. Ok. I have updated my table which should be correct and standard way to do. Please take a look.

Comment: @user976050 Sorry, but do not exactly remember the last table definition, what exactly have you updated?

Comment: you can refer to my standard and correct way to do it.. for the updated table.

Comment: @user976050 yes, this way you have simply added a column, with datatype number which you will use as ID. For further details plz see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `time` is nullable then it cannot form part of a `PRIMARY KEY` but it can be part of e `UNIQUE` constraint. Note that a key is a key and designating a key as 'primary' is arbitrary and not compulsory.

Adding `Testid` as a surrogate key will only work when you have a natural key to begin with. Therefore:

EITHER natural key only:

```
Create table TEST
(
 testno number(5) not null,
 testpaper varchar(2) not null,
 time date, 
 CONSTRAINT Pa_Uqs UNIQUE (testno, testpaper, time) 
);
```

OR natural key plus surrogate key:

```
Create table TEST
(
 Testid number(1) not null,
 testno number(5) not null,
 testpaper varchar(2) not null,
 time date, 
 CONSTRAINT Pa_Pks PRIMARY KEY (Testid), 
 CONSTRAINT Pa_Uqs UNIQUE (testno, testpaper, time) 
);
```